# STM32F767ZIT6 Nucleo openocd flash

Tags: c++, c, openocd, stm32f7

STM32F767ZIT6 Nucleo board and trying to flash it with blinky code from templates

- have populated all the CMSIS and required drivers.
- Installed GNU MCU eclipse plugin.
- Built the code
- Configured openOCD
- When trying to debug the code its returns these errors

```
GNU MCU Eclipse 64-bits Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00254-g2ec04e4e (2017-11-10-11:34)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v29 API v2 SWIM v18 VID 0x0483 PID 0x374B
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.243922
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: hardware has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : device id = 0x10016451
Info : flash size = 2048kbytes
Info : Single Bank 2048 kiB STM32F76x/77x found
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc
semihosting is enabled
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc, semihosting
Info : Padding image section 0 with 4 bytes
Info : Padding image section 1 with 1 bytes
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x20000046 msp: 0xfffffffc, semihosting
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 00000000 pc: 0xf924f000 msp: 0xb083b500, semihosting
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 00000000 pc: 0xf924f000 msp: 0xb083b500, semihosting
===== arm v7m registers
(0) r0 (/32): 0x00000000
(1) r1 (/32): 0x00000000
(2) r2 (/32): 0x00000000
(3) r3 (/32): 0x00000000
(4) r4 (/32): 0x00000000
(5) r5 (/32): 0x00000000
(6) r6 (/32): 0x00000000
(7) r7 (/32): 0x00000000
(8) r8 (/32): 0x00000000
(9) r9 (/32): 0x00000000
(10) r10 (/32): 0x00000000
(11) r11 (/32): 0x00000000
(12) r12 (/32): 0x00000000
(13) sp (/32): 0xB083B500
(14) lr (/32): 0xFFFFFFFF
(15) pc (/32): 0xF924F000
(16) xPSR (/32): 0x00000000
(17) msp (/32): 0xB083B500
(18) psp (/32): 0x00000000
(19) primask (/1): 0x00
(20) basepri (/8): 0x00
(21) faultmask (/1): 0x00
(22) control (/2): 0x00
(23) d0 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(24) d1 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(25) d2 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(26) d3 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(27) d4 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(28) d5 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(29) d6 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(30) d7 (/64): 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
(31) d8 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(32) d9 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(33) d10 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(34) d11 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(35) d12 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(36) d13 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(37) d14 (/64): 0x0000000000000000
(38) d15 (/64): 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
(39) fpscr (/32): 0x00000000
===== Cortex-M DWT registers
(40) dwt_ctrl (/32)
(41) dwt_cyccnt (/32)
(42) dwt_0_comp (/32)
(43) dwt_0_mask (/4)
(44) dwt_0_function (/32)
(45) dwt_1_comp (/32)
(46) dwt_1_mask (/4)
(47) dwt_1_function (/32)
(48) dwt_2_comp (/32)
(49) dwt_2_mask (/4)
(50) dwt_2_function (/32)
(51) dwt_3_comp (/32)
(52) dwt_3_mask (/4)
(53) dwt_3_function (/32)


mem.ld  is as below
MEMORY

    {
      FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 2048K
      RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 512K
    }
```

I am guessing it could be something to do with the memory map. Can't figure it out.
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f767zi.html

*****Real newbie at this****(
- ( I am using Windows and eclipse Photon)

Comment: Is it C, or C++?

Comment: The code is the blinky template in C